# We have discouraged Basic authentication in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I recently received an email from Google:

```
Hello Google Kubernetes Engine Customer,

We’re writing to remind you that we have discouraged Basic authentication in
Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). This authentication strategy has been 
disabled by default since version 1.12, because it does not align with
Googles’ security best practices and will no longer be supported in GKE,
starting from v1.19.

You’re receiving this message, because you’re currently using a 
static password to authenticate for one or more of your GKE clusters.
```

How can I avoid using a static password, where is this kept? I don't remember setting this up.

I've referenced https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster. Am I right to understand I didn't do anything particularly to fall out of compliance except using the GCP automation prior to 1.12 and now need to take some sort of action to remain within current standards?

Want to ensure I understand the history and scope of this change and perhaps have a simplified video I can follow verbatim to ensure I don't fall into a downtime I can't get out of. Or just a set of commands if this is standard to maintain my current workflow and authenticate on my user that already has current access prior to 1.12 when I deploy my app.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling basic authentication should not result in any downtime for your cluster.
The preferred method for authentication with the API server is OAuth and this should already be enabled for your cluster.  You can check that this is working by running the following commands:

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud container clusters get-credentials $CLUSTERNAME --zone $ZONE
```

Running any `kubectl` command, e.g. `kubectl cluster-info`

Assuming all goes well there (and I can't think of any reason it will not), you'd then run

`gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME --no-enable-basic-auth`

in order to disable basic auth.

EDIT: If you need to (re)enable basic auth, you can run the foolowing command:

`gcloud container clusters update --username=$USER --password=$PASS`

where $USER and $PASS are the username and password you were previously using (or a new user/password if you choose).

Of course, if you have any automations using the Cloud SDK which use basic auth, you'd need to update those as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But before I do, could you update the commands with their back out counterparts in case something goes awry?

Comment: Also, I tried gcloud container clusters list to see what my clusters even were and received ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.list) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.list" permission(s) for "projects/<my_project_id>".

Comment: Added command to turn back on basic auth.

Comment: Thanks Gari. But is it possible I don't currently have a cluster configured if I can't find one? Once I figure out this Cluster piece you mentioned I should be ready to try the change. See my second comment and thanks for assisting, I know these are rather new-to-GCP questions.

Comment: Hmm ... odd that your account does not have permission to list clusters.  Do you see any clusters via the Cloud Console UI?