# How an app deployed on GKE can deploy other app on same GCP project without authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a java application that is deployed on GKE cluster. Let's call it the "orchestrator"

The application should be able to deploy other applications on same GCP project where the "orchestrator" app is running (can be same GKE or different GKE cluster), using helm cli commands.

We were able to do that using Google Service Account authentication, where the JSON key is provided to the "orchestrator" and we could use it to generate tokens.

My question is.. since both the "orchestrator" and the others apps are running on same GCP project (sometimes on same GKE cluster), is there a way to use some default credentials auto discovered by GCP, instead of generating and providing a Service Account JSON key to the "orchestrator" app?

That way, the customer won't need to expose this Key to our system and the authentication will be happened behind the scenes, without our app intervention.

Is there something a GCP admin can do which make this use case work seamlessly?

Comment: How did you authenticate it? Did you use the SA key as a Kubernetes Secret? Also did you try to use methods mentioned in [Authenticating to Google Cloud with service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform)? According to best practices, if you want to authenticate an application, you should use a Service Account. Also did you check [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication)? I also guess you are unable to do any changes in the cluster, only in the application

Comment: @Pjoters actually a SA already attach to Compute Engine VMs already, so when I run a simple k8s job which runs "gcloud auth list" command from within the job container, I see the credentials of this SA in there, and also "gcloud container clusters list" returns the correct cluster list. I wonder what is necessary, given this information, to make same pod run "kubectl" or "helm" command if the credentials are there?

Comment: When you are using [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#key-types), you have to use keys to authenticate - `Each service account is associated with a public/private RSA key pair.` As you are wokring on `GKE cluster`, did you consider to use `Workload identity`, like mentioned in [Best practices for using and managing SA](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-using-and-managing-service-accounts)?

Answer (score 1):

I will elaborate on my comment.

When you are using a `Service Account`, you have to use keys to authenticate - Each service account is associated with a public/private RSA key pair. As you are working on GKE cluster, did you consider using Workload identity, like mentioned in Best practices for using and managing SA?

According to [Best practices for using and managing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-using-and-managing-service-accounts) all non-human accounts should be represented by [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts):

> Service accounts represent non-human users. They're intended for scenarios where a workload, such as a custom application, needs to access resources or perform actions without end-user involvement.

So in general, whenever you want to provide some permissions to applications, you should use `Service Account`.

In [Types of keys for service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#key-types) you can find information, that all `Service Accounts` needs `RSA` pair key:

> Each service account is associated with a public/private RSA key pair. The Service Account Credentials API uses this internal key pair to create short-lived service account credentials, and to sign blobs and JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). This key pair is known as the Google-managed key pair.
>
> In addition, you can create multiple public/private RSA key pairs, known as user-managed key pairs, and use the private key to authenticate with Google APIs. This private key is known as a service account key.

You could also think about [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-using-and-managing-service-accounts#use-workload-identity), but I am not sure if this would fulfill your needs as there are still many unknowns about your environment.

Just as additional information, there was something called `Basic Authentication` which could be an option for you, but due to security reasons it's not supported since GKE 1.19. This was mentioned in another stack case: [We have discouraged Basic authentication in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68321345/).

**To sum up:**

Best Practice to provide permissions for non-human accounts is to use `Service Account`. Each service account requires a pair of `RSA Keys` and you can create multiple keys.
Good Practice is also to use `Workload Identity` if you have this option, but due to lack of details it is hard to determine if this would work in your scenario.

**Additional links:**

- [Authenticating to the Kubernetes API server](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication)
- [Use the Default Service Account to access the API server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#use-the-default-service-account-to-access-the-api-server)

Comment: Thanks @Pjoters for you details response. The main motivation is to prevent the user from exposing its SA Key.. and as you mentioned there some ways to do so, like Workload Identity. Eventually, using the service account that is attached to the resource (GKE cluster) did the work, by using the default credentials mechanism provided by Google Java API.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is to use use default credentials approach mentioned here :
[Finding credentials automatically](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically). Instead of exposing the SA key to our App, the GCP admin can attach the same SA to the GKE cluster resource (see attached screenshot), and the default credentials mechanism will use that SA credentials to get access the APIs and resources (depends on the SA roles and permissions).

[image]